# Alphanumeric not working with underscore

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using the following REGEX and what I need is 
to accept only alphanumeric values with the following condition

```
1.Should not start with number
2.Accept underscore between character 
3.Can have space after the value
```

e.g.

aa_bb
a1_a2

I tried with the following which is not working well:

```
@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(_.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$",
```

Comment: _Should not start with number:_ What do you think `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+` does?

Comment: do you want spaces in between too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_.]+\s?$"
```

use this regex.

your regex has several flaws

- `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+` will allow numbers at the starting of the test string.
- there is no space at the end so it will not allow space.

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/xG7cT9

Comment: I think a better regex would be ^[a-zA-Z]\w*[\ ]?$ your regex accept tab and another chars at the end of a string

Comment: This forces more than one character.

Comment: @GabrielMonteiroNepomuceno what about the `.` op wants

Comment: @Rawling yes the op is not specific about it. you can change `+` to `*` anytime you like

Comment: The problem is with the "\s" you should use "\ " insted since he don't want tabs